# Trying to solve searching columns across two sheets for X value - if so return corresponding Y value

Tags: google-sheets

I need a formula for a cell (A1 on the sheet 'Class') to search two columns on two sheets (Q:Q on 'Class' and A:A on 'Names') for an X value and if any value in either column matches the value in cell B1 on 'Class' then returns the value in the corresponding column on whichever sheet it was found on - R:R on 'Class' and B:B on 'Names'

I have the formula to search one column or the other but not both.

This is a formula that works for the column on the same sheet:

```
=INDEX(R:R,MATCH(B3,Q:Q,0))
```

Or the other sheet:

```
=INDEX(Names!B:B,MATCH(B3,Names!A:A,0))
```

But I have no idea how to get one formula to searching both...

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Put them together with IFERROR. If the first fails, the second is attempted.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(R:R,MATCH(B3,Q:Q,0)), INDEX(Names!B:B,MATCH(B3,Names!A:A,0)))
```

If neither match then #N/A is the result.

Comment: Is there any way to get a blank cell if neither match rather than #N/A?